# how to subscribe Outlook Resources room's calendar

Tags: graph, outlook, delegates, resources, subscription

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks

Based on the link above, using Microsoft Graph REST API, an app can subscribe to changes on messages,events, cantacts etc.

Is there a way to subscribe events on Outlook Resources(such as conference room calendar) when login using a principal account which can delegate Outlook Resource(conference room)?

I only saw top level subscription like : me/messages, me/contacts, me/events
but how to subscribe events for other users or Resources?